# How do I align the hover/dropdown menu with the my custom context button symbol?

Tags: highcharts

I have tried using my own custom image url for the context menu, however, the hover does not align with the actual image itself. It is similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/858m3kxv/

You can see in the fiddle that the hover is misaligned. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

```
    title: {
        text: 'Custom context menu symbol'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }],

    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/images/ico/favicon-192x192.png)'
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can position the image by using `symbolX` and `symbolY` properties.

```
exporting: {
  buttons: {
    contextButton: {
      symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/images/ico/favicon-192x192.png)',
      symbolX: 18,
      symbolY: 18
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qLc7fxap/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.symbolX